# How to solve multiple concurrent writes with MongoDB and two-phase commit?

Tags: mongodb, concurrency

I have implemented two-phase commits for MongoDB as described in MongoDB's [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/). Basically, this works fine. It was especially easy as all I care about is inserting new documents, I never update them.

Yet, I worry about a particular scenario where I am not sure how to solve this. So any help would be appreciated.

Given: A collection containing documents with the following structure:

```
id: ...,
subId: ...
payload: {
  ...
}
```

There may be more than one document with the same `id`, but all documents with the same `id` have an increasing `subId`. So, you have something like:

- 1 - 1
- 1 - 2
- 2 - 1
- 3 - 1
- 3 - 2
- 3 - 3

Each insert only deals with one `id`, but potentially provides more than one document. So this means that there may be an insert with documents `3 - 4` and `3 - 5`, but never an insert with documents `3 - 4` and `4 - 1`.

The `id` and `subId` fields are calculated by the client inserting the data.

When inserting more than one document, this insert is covered by a 2PC. So either all documents are committed or none.

The problem now arises with the second phase of the 2PC. As I do not want other clients to be able to read uncommitted data, there is a flag within each document which tells me whether the document has already been committed. Once all documents have been written and the transaction has been set to 'completed', as a very last step the documents are marked as committed.

So now what happens if I try to insert `3 - 4` and `3 - 5`, both get written, the transaction is completed, and `3 - 4` is marked as committed, and just before `3 - 5` gets marked as committed, another client reads all documents with id `3`, sees subId `4`as highest one, creates a new document with `3 - 5` and inserts it?

Then the commit fails and I have mixed version numbers from two transactions.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, forget about it ... typical case of "I see it when I write it". The scenario I described is no problem as `3 - 5` was already written by the first transaction, it is just not committed. So as there is a unique index constraint on `id - subId` another transaction can not interfere.

Problem solved.